# Make alsamixer changes permanent

Tags: sound, alsa, macbook

I have installed ubuntu GNOME 14.04 in my macbook Pro 13" mid 2012, and something is wrong with the headphones jack, a red led is on and it just can be turned off with the alsamixer command and muting a special section (I'm sorry for not remember the setting, I'm on OS X for work reasons)

I already know how to fix it, but I want to know how to save the setting in the alsamixer, because with every reboot the red led is back.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The command `alsactl store` saves the mixer settings into `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state`; the command `alsactl restore` reloads them.

In theory, these commands should be executed automatically when the computer is started up and shut down.
Check whether that file exists, and if the saved mixer controls have the correct value.
If not, you might need to execute these commands manually.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work (at least on Ubuntu 20.04). I made a solution to "freeze" the mixer settings, check it out https://askubuntu.com/questions/1318951/how-to-remove-app-permissions-to-change-microphone-settings/1323705#1323705