# How to remove app permissions to change microphone settings?

Tags: 20.04, sound, permissions, alsa, microphone

My microphone has background noise when the `Capture` setting is set to 100.

[image: Default config]

I read this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/479294/make-alsamixer-changes-permanent), reconfigured and executed `sudo alsactl store` to keep the configuration.

[image: Custom config]

But here's the catch, doesn't matter if my custom settings are stored, when I open an application like Chrome, Discord, Microsoft Teams, whatever that uses microphone, automatically my settings are overridden, usually to `Capture` set to 100, returning the background noise.

Is there an option to deny any application to change the configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a script ([AlsaMixerFreeze repository](https://github.com/Kafels/AlsaMixerFreeze)) to watch and restore automatically when it changes.

> The alsactl.sh script listens alsactl monitor events. When an event is
> trigger, it means something tried to change the configuration and this
> script runs automatically alsactl restore to return the custom
> configuration.